# Django queryset .count() .filter() not working on custom model manager

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model manager that filters a queryset and returns the Records objects that have started today, that is: `time_start.day == datetime.now().day`. I can't use .count() or filter on the model manager:

I get the errors

```
>>>> Records.objects.today().count()
     TypeError: count() takes exactly one argument (0 given)

>>>> Records.objects.today().filter(owner=self.request.user)
     AttributeError 'list' object has no attribute 'filter'
```

What should I return? not sure how can I get this working. This is the manager:

```
class RecordManager(models.Manager):

    use_for_related_fields = True

    def today(self, **kwargs):
        today = datetime.now(pytz.utc)
        yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)

        initial_queryset = self.filter(time_start__gte=yesterday, **kwargs)
        return_list = []
        for record in initial_queryset:
            if (record.time_start).day == today.day:
                return_list.append(record)
        return return_list
```

This is the model:

```
class Records(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity, null=True)
    time_start = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    time_end = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    objects = RecordManager()

    def is_running(self):
        if self.time_end is None:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def total_time(self):
        return ((self.time_end-self.time_start).seconds)/60

    def string_time_start(self):
        if self.time_start:
            return self.time_start.strftime("%H:%M %P")
        else:
            return None

    def string_time_end(self):
        if self.time_end:
            return self.time_end.strftime("%H:%M %P")
        else:
            return None

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s - %s" % (self.activity.title, self.string_time_start())
```

Thanks a lot for you help.

Comment: Try Records.objects.count()

Comment: That works correctly.

Comment: I'm happy to hear this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning a list, not a queryset, from your manager method, so naturally none of the queryset methods like count and filter will work.

**Edit**

I'm not quite sure why you're doing any of that. Seems like you just want to query the records between 12.00am and 11.59pm today, which is a simple query:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
start = datetime.datetime.combine(today, datetime.time(0))
end = datetime.datetime.combine(today, datetime.time(23, 59))
return self.filter(time_start__gte=start, time_start__lte=end)
```

Comment: But then, how can I return a queryset? If what I need is to compare `time_start.day` with `datetime.today().day`. Should I post a different question for this?

Answer (score 0):

As @Daniel Roseman wrote, I was returning a list when I needed to return a queryset. Just in case someone reads the question and wants to see the code that actually worked:

```
class RecordManager(models.Manager):

    use_for_related_fields = True

    def today(self, **kwargs):
        today = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)
        reference_date = datetime.datetime(today.year, today.month, today.day, tzinfo=pytz.utc)

        return self.filter(time_start__gte=reference_date, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score -1):

The right solution is

```
Records.objects.count()
```

Comment: -1 This is not the right solution - as it doesn't apply the filtering rules that the ``today`` attribute was supposed to apply.